# systemC : sc_time_stamp() comparing with an other variable

Tags: c++, systemc

I have  a problem with usinf `sc_time_stamp()`

I want to do an operation (write the sentence below) just at the `time = 20`

so:

`1t1 = sc_time_stamp();
if (t1.to_string() ==  "20" ) { cout<<"Current time is "<< t1 << endl; }1`

but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that function but... according to [this page](http://www.asic-world.com/systemc/systemc_time1.html)... the method `to_string()` of `sc_time` (the type of `t1`, I suppose) print non only numeric value of the the time, but also the unit of measure ("s"? "ms"? "ns"?).

So, by example (if the unit of measure is second), could work

```
if ( t1.to_string() ==  "20 s" )
    cout<<"Current time is "<< t1 << endl;
```

But I suggest (fixed the time resolution with `sc_set_time_resolution()`) to check numerical values, not string values; if I undestand well, something like

```
if ( t1 ==  20 )
    cout<<"Current time is "<< t1.to_string() << endl;
```

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.